# Did Jesus consider OT events to be literal history?

Tags: history, life-of-jesus, old-testament

Did Jesus consider the historic references in the OT to be literal in the sense that people and events where historical as recorded or did he view them as symbolic/figurative or did he pick and choose? Can we construct what his view must have been on the literal historicity of the OT based on his own usage of it?

Comment: Related question: [What was Jesus' view on the authority of Scripture?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3949)

Comment: As written this seems to be a truth question.  Given the answer, would it be appropriate to modify it to be a biblical basis question for the idea that Jesus considered OT events to be literal history?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "Yes."  Jesus quoted from the Old Testament scriptures as if they were authoritative, and as if they were the very words of God.  The passages of the OT that are historical were regarded by Him as historical.

Jesus affirmed the historical existence of Jonah (Matt. 12:40), Noah (Matt. 24:37-38), and Adam and Eve (Matt. 19:4-6).