# What was Satan's view on the authority of Scripture?

Tags: bible, satan, authorship, inspiration

Does the Bible give us any indication about what Satan's own view of the Scriptures and their authority as divine testimony is? Does the way he uses it or the way he responds to those who use it tell us anything about his understanding of their inspiration/authority?

Comment: Parallel question: [What was Jesus' view on the authority of Scripture?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3949)

Answer (score 3):

While the oft-cited adage that "the Devil can quote scripture for his own purposes" is not, as some think, an actual Biblical quotation, support for the idea is definitely found in the Bible.  (See [Matthew chapter 4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%204:1-11), for example.)  This doesn't really demonstrate anything either way about Satan's willingness to accept the scriptures as authoritative or authentic, but simply a cynical tendency to use any rhetorical tool that he thinks will be effective.

We do know that ["the devils believe [in God] and tremble"](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%202:19), and that they acknowledge the power of his authorized servants but not his name alone ([Acts 19: 13-16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2019:13-16),) but very little is said of Satan or his servants and their relationship with the scriptures.

Comment: It's not a lot, but we do actually have a record both of Satan using and _being confronted with_ Scripture and his (lack of) a comeback. See also: [What was Jesus' view on the authority of Scripture?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3949)

Comment: @Caleb - Yes, in Matt 4:10 Satan didn't refute the authority of Scripture.